# MySQL Basic Commands

Tags: mysql, sql

I am just a new beginner in MySQL and I wanted to write the a SELECT statement that returns customers IDs and customer names(alphabetical order) for customers who live in Indiana, Ohio,Michigan, and Illinois, and whose names begin with  the letters A or B.

Here is the CUSTOMER_TBL structure using the DESCRIBE CUSTOMER_TBL;

```
    Name                         Null?                      Type
    -------------------------------------------------------------
   CUST_ID                      NOT NULL                   VARCHAR2(10)
   CUST_NAME                    NOT NULL                   VARCHAR2(30)
   CUST_ADDRESS                 NOT NULL                   VARCHAR2(20)
   CUST_CITY                    NOT NULL                   VARCHAR2(12)
   CUST_STATE                   NOT NULL                   CHAR(2)
   CUST_ZIP                     NOT NULL                   CHAR2(5)
   CUST_PHONE                                              NUMBER(10)
   CUST_FAX                                                NUMBER(10)
```

Here is my solution.I just need to know if I am correct. thanks

```
   SELECT CUST_ID,CUST_NAME FROM CUSTOMER_TBL
   WHERE IN('Indiana','Ohio','Ohio','Michigan','Illinois') AND WHERE LIKE(A% OR B%)
   ORDER BY CUST_ID,CUST_NAME
```

Comment: "Where " clause is completely wrong , the query is simple learn the syntax. i just u to learn from here "http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp". It will be better than giving u the answer

Comment: ... and if you need to learn something about **w3schools.com** itself, you need to go here: **http://w3fools.com/**

Comment: first of all clear your basics, you missed to write column name after where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CUST_STATE` is a `CHAR(2)` column so I assume that it contains state codes, not state names. So instead of Indiana, Ohio etc you should use state codes:

```
SELECT CUST_ID, CUST_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER_TBL
WHERE CUST_STATE IN ('IN','OH','MI','IL') AND (
    CUST_NAME LIKE 'A%' OR
    CUST_NAME LIKE 'B%'
)
ORDER BY CUST_NAME
```

Correct the state codes in case they are wrong.

Comment: @deadrunk: I noticed the typo (if that is what you were referring to) and fixed it.

Comment: yeah, i was talking about the first `like` expression

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CUST_ID,CUST_NAME FROM CUSTOMER_TBL
WHERE CUST_STATE IN('Indiana','Ohio','Ohio','Michigan','Illinois') AND (CUST_NAME LIKE 'A%' OR CUST_NAME LIKE 'B%') 
ORDER BY CUST_ID,CUST_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of things wrong in your query:

- You should first try it, not just asking is it correct or not.
- When nesting conditions in the `WHERE` statement, don't repeat the where itslef.
- You should mention the column you are trying to match against the condition.

So, your query should look like:

```
SELECT CUST_ID, CUST_NAME 
FROM CUSTOMER_TBL
WHERE CUSTOMER_City IN('Indiana','Ohio','Ohio','Michigan','Illinois') 
    AND ( CUST_NAME LIKE 'A%' OR CUST_NAME LIKE 'B%' )
ORDER BY CUST_ID,CUST_NAME
```